# Can I bind the visibility of a button to the IsSelected property of its containing ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am working on a Windows Store app. One page contains a `ListView` that has a `StackPanel` with some `TextBlocks` and three buttons:

[image]

I would like to have the three buttons be visible only when the `ListItem` to which they belong is selected. I've tried every possible arrangement of `Binding` on the `Visibility` property of the  buttons, but nothing has worked so far. It appears that the constrained set of binding types for WinRT apps is preventing me from using a known solution. Is there anything that I can do?

I'm currently trying to think it through from the perspective of manipulating the object in code inside the `ListView` `SelectionChanged` event handler, but nothing has worked out yet.

Here is the XAML for the ItemTemplate:

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SessionBlock}" DoubleTapped="StackPanel_DoubleTapped">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SessionTitle}" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SessionStepCount}">
                            <Run Text="{Binding StepsCount}" />
                            <Run Text=" Steps" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="&#xE17E;&#xE102;"
                            Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" />
                    <Button Content="&#xE17E;&#xE104;"
                            Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" />
                    <Button Content="&#xE17E;&#xE107;"
                            Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `TemplatedParent` for the same

to begin with declare a bool to visibility converter in resources

eg

```
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

then in xaml apply the following binding to Visibility, with the above declared converter

```
    Visibility="{Binding TemplatedParent.IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

so the trick here is to find the TemplatedParent of the datatemplate which is content presenter and then its TemplatedParent which is ListViewItem and IsSelected property is what you are looking for

so your example could be as follows

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SessionBlock}" DoubleTapped="StackPanel_DoubleTapped">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SessionTitle}" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SessionStepCount}">
                        <Run Text="{Binding StepsCount}" />
                        <Run Text=" Steps" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Content="&#xE17E;&#xE102;"
                        Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding TemplatedParent.IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                <Button Content="&#xE17E;&#xE104;"
                        Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding TemplatedParent.IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                <Button Content="&#xE17E;&#xE107;"
                        Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding TemplatedParent.IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

in example above I applied the same to to all three buttons, you can also put all of them in a stack panel and apply a single binding to it so shorten the code.

Comment: I made this change, but now my app crashes when I try to start it. It appears that the documentation hints that TemplatedParent may only be available inside a ControlTemplate and not a DataTemplate?

Comment: Crash is not a normal behavior of binding errors, it simply does not work when incorrect. I am successfully able to bind the same here. BTW is there any exception you could notice? Is it possible for you to post a working sample? May I have a look.

Comment: There's no exception. That's very odd, but it is objectively true that the program stops running and Visual Studio shows that it is no longer debugging. I'm getting extremely frustrated with the limited binding capabilities in the WinRT variety of XAML. I do appreciate your offer of taking a closer look at a working sample, but I'm not sure that I want to post all of the source code of my app, and it's not easy to extract just a subset to make this screen workable.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a test app which demonstrate the issue. I am curious if I get the same crash behavior. Till now I could only test the data template on a list view bound to a collection of strings. You may also try to tweak this binding and perhaps others too and see if there is anything you can figure out.

Answer (score -1):

I was never able to find a way to do what I want through XAML, but I was able to accomplish it with some code-behind. Sadly, the stuff in the code-behind was really obscure and it took some lucky and diligent Google-fu to find the incantation that did it. Real credit for this goes to  this blog page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx

What I did was, I added a slightly modified version of the code that from that blog page:

```
private List<childItem> findVisualChildren<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject {
    List<childItem> results = new List<childItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++) {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem) {
            results.Add((childItem)child);
        } else {
            results.AddRange(findVisualChildren<childItem>(child));
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

It recursively searches the children of a visual element for elements of a given type and returns them all in a list. Neat, but doesn't this all seem like jibber-jabber? Win Forms at least presented a very obvious approach to interacting with child nodes.

Then, that method is called from inside the `SelectionChanged` event handler of the `ListView`:

```
private void SessionsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    for (int itemIdx = 0; itemIdx < SessionsList.Items.Count; itemIdx++) {
        ListViewItem eachItem = (ListViewItem)SessionsList.ContainerFromIndex(itemIdx);
        // Content Presenter stuff is from the blog post. I have no idea.
        var presenters = findVisualChildren<ContentPresenter>(eachItem);
        if (presenters != null && presenters.Count > 0) {
            var buttonsList = findVisualChildren<Button>(presenters[0]);
            if (buttonsList != null && buttonsList.Count > 0) {
                for (int buttonIdx = 0; buttonIdx < buttonsList.Count; buttonIdx++) {
                    Button eachButton = (Button)buttonsList[buttonIdx];
                    if (itemIdx == SessionsList.SelectedIndex) {
                        eachButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    } else {
                        eachButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see that the handler iterates over each item in the ListView. For each, it grabs the `ContentPresenter` whatever that is. It then uses the `findVisualChildren` on that object to find all buttons that belong to it. If it is operating on the currently-selected item, the buttons are made visible; otherwise, they are collapsed.

It works exactly as I want, but I can't help but feel disappointed that I just couldn't find the right binding spell to do this 'the right way.'

Am I right in thinking that the WinRT version of WPF has badly-crippled binding abilities? It seems to be a far cry from what available in WPF for the non-Store desktop apps that I work on.